# JPA Relationship with 3 Entities Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
public class Attribute {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "attribute_id") private String attributeId;
    @NotNull @Column(name = "attribute_name") private String attributeName;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = AttributeValue.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "attribute_id")
    private List<AttributeValue> attributeValue;
}


@Entity
public class AttributeValue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "value_id")
    private String valueId;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "attribute_id")
    private Attribute attribute;

    @NotNull @Column(name = "value") private String value;
}

@Entity
public class Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "model_id")
    private String modelId;

    @NotNull private String name;
    @NotNull private String desc;
}
```

I am new to Spring boot JPA. I want a relationship between the above mentioned 3 entities as in the following JSON String. 
Please note that Attributes and AttributeValues are Predefined. I want to insert/select the user selected values of Attributes and AttributeValues for each Model.
Thanks in advance.

```
{
    'Model':[
        {
            'name' : 'M1',
            'desc' : 'Model M1',
            'selectedAttributes' :[
                {
                    'attributeId' : 'A1',
                    'attributeValues' : [
                        {
                            'valueId' : 1
                        },
                        {
                            'valueId' :3
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is there a question? BTW there's no association between `Model` and `Attribute`, is that intentional?

Comment: @crizzis... I will describe my question... Attributes are defined as Color, Size,Resolution etc. Attribute Values Red,Blue,Green,Small,Medium,Large,XL,XXL,1080p,720p etc. This would be in One to many relationship. Now when a user add a Shirt, He would Choose _Color_ , _Size_ as attributes and _Red_,_Blue_ and _XL_,_XXL_ as attribute values of the respected attributes. How to make the relationship to achieve the above scenario.